# How do I get Bootstrap popover 'data-placement' of existing popover?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I need to re-position an existing popover once Ajax data has been returned (size of data returned will vary) and I am doing this by modifying .css `top` and `left` for the popover in the completion block.

I can read the height and width with :

```
$popoverElement.height()
$popoverElement.width()
```

Then re-calculate positions for `$popoverElement.css({top: newtop})` and `$popoverElement.css({left: newleft})`.

From looking at other posts, this seems to be the only option.

If `data-placement` of current popover is `right`, I just need to change top (to adjust the vertical position of the popover). However, if the `data-placement` is `left` then I also need to change the horizontal position of the popover.

How can I read the `data-placement` attribute of the popover, to use in an if clause? I am setting this attribute correctly in the page, but don't know how to reference it in my function.

**EDIT :** The reason I'm doing this, is because the arrow is no longer aligned when the popover resizes with the new content - this is the problem I am trying to solve, if there's a better way to achieve this, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from the bs data object associated with the popover instance.

```
var popoverData = $popoverElement.data('bs.popover');    
var popoverPlacement = popoverData.options.placement;
console.log(popoverPlacement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `data()` to read the current value (assuming the popover() has already been instantiated):

`$popoverElement.data("placement");`

http://www.codeply.com/go/33aPVnvfyy